# LocationServices PendingIntent vs Service

Tags: android, service, android-pendingintent, location-services

I'm trying to make an optimized application that runs background 100% of the time.
It receives location updates and post them to a server.

**I'd like to know if im doing things the way i should.**

At this moment my app has a service that requestLocationUpdates using LocationServices API. 
It accumulate locations and try to send them to the server.

This services is self terminated if no more locations are pending left.

**Also i have an alarm to wake up this service every while.**

So next time the service wake up, start a new session of GooglePlayServices and receive locations again.

I understand that using pendingIntents is better for unmanaged location tracking, but i still think that need the background service to upload locations in a timely manner.

**- Should i stop using alarm raised services?**

**- Is there any way to start requesting location updates without user intervention / activity?**

**- Is a broadcastReceiver capable of managing heavy work like network posting?**

Got [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) from google locationServices doc:

```
public abstract PendingResult<Status> requestLocationUpdates
(GoogleApiClient client, LocationRequest request, PendingIntent
callbackIntent)
```

> Requests location updates with a callback on the specified
>   PendingIntent.
>
> This method is suited for the background use cases, more specifically
>   for receiving location updates, even when the app has been killed by
>   the system. In order to do so, use a PendingIntent for a started
>   service. For foreground use cases, the LocationListener version of the
>   method is recommended, see requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient,
>   LocationRequest, LocationListener).

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to start requesting location updates without user intervention / activity?

Yes, you can create nice scenarios setting up alarm with specified frequency. Even the app is not working, your alarm wakes up device, receives location and then sends to server. After it's work done, device sleeps again. Please check this [project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll), here super scenario from commonsguy.

> Is a broadcastReceiver capable of managing heavy work like network posting?

Yes, it does, You'll probably send location to server.

> Should i stop using alarm raised services?

Depends on your tracking style.. Consider examples

- Receiving location and sending to server at every 10 minutes (or more)
- Receiving location and sending to server at every 5 seconds (like realtime tracking)

Probably, for the first example, you will set repeating alarm and then wake up device, receive and send location, and finally allow device's sleep (10 minutes). In this case, you must stop everything about tracking (location services, network operations)

But in the second example, you cant set alarm with lower frequency like 5 seconds. You should have not-stop background service (theoretically) and make location request with 5 seconds interval. In this case, you shouldn't stop resources like (awake device, location requests, network operations). And finally user uninstalls the app :-)

Bottom line, follow commonsguy's [project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll)

Comment: Thanks in advance.

I already have a service alarm raised working like 1st scenario. It request location updates, send them to server and stopSelf() after emptying a locations quee. 

In my case, i need to upload locations at a user determinated frequency, say for example, between 1 and 10 minutes. 

Do you think i should accomplish that with a BroadCast service and have an alarm raised service to start all over again if device or service is sleeping. 
I know this could be a lot of work: getAppSettings, registrer Google location services API, geofenceApi, and so on.

Comment: Yes you can, but must be careful of wakefulness duration. Rely on completing all process in specified time, define a timeout. if it exceeds, shutdown everything, allow sleeping until next alarm tick ! For instance, you shouldn't wait to receive location forever. If you check the link above, you'll get the points that you must be aware of.

Comment: All right. I saw that link but it doesn't use LocationServices API and i think that locations app are different from that on .

Comment: It uses, 
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/locpoll/LocationPollerService.java#L98

Comment: by LocationServices, i meant LocationServices API from google : http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/location/index.html

Comment: so whats the difference between them ?

Comment: basically, the way you request locations. I know that this API is an interface to them. But i would need to connect googleAPI client to start receiving them. 

Thank you again. I will check out that project to look for detailed techniques.

Comment: So you wanna use fusedlocation provider or geofence api ?

Comment: i use both, and register them in that alarm raised service.
And that's where i tought that should be broadcasting locations and forget about this service.